# How are PCI(e) errors propagated to userspace in case of errors?

Tags: memory, pci-express, io

PCIe supports [various error reporting mechanisms](https://pcisig.com/sites/default/files/specification_documents/ECN_Internal-Error-Reporting_24Apr08.pdf), and I can see how a device driver would [interface with these capabilities](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/PCI/pcieaer-howto.txt) to handle specific error types and reinitialize the device in question as required in case of errors.

However, how would a PCIe read error be indicated to a userspace program reading from memory-mapped address space in case the read cannot be satisfied, e.g. due to a bus error or a disconnected hot plug device?

As far as I understand it, there are two basic possibilities: Either invalid data is propagated to the reading application (e.g. all reads would return 0x00 or 0xFF), or the PCI error results in an error state or interrupt to the CPU which will be handled by the kernel and translated to a signal (like SIGBUS on a Unix).

(For writes, this would presumably not work, at least if they are implemented as posted PCIe transactions, as the userspace application would not be blocked on the memory access: A signal, if delivered at all, would arrive asynchronously some time after the failed write.)

The latter would seem like a safer choice, but I've found mentions of both [a signal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40115097/linux-mmap-access-to-pci-memory-region-from-user-space-application) and a special value being sent ([here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/powerpc/eeh-pci-error-recovery.txt) and [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/HardwareDrivers/Conceptual/ThunderboltDevGuide/Basics02/Basics02.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011138-CH4-SW1)).

My question is not limited to a specific system, but as the implementation of PCIe errors probably depends heavily on both the hardware and kernel architecture of the system in question, system-specific answers would also be very welcome.

Comment: I've seen both PCI errors reported in syslog (so an interrupt was raised) and `ff` returned on read in that case, so I assume the answer is "both".

Comment: An interrupt being reported in syslog could happen asynchronously though, with the signal not being sent to the reading application, right?

Comment: IIRC the application (lspci) didn't receive a signal, but that's a Linux kernel implementation issue, not a PCIe bus implementation issue. Nothing prevents the kernel from sending a signal, AFAIK the address causing the violation is logged.